# Unable to upload a document via php

Tags: php

I have this simple script I coded to up upload a CV. But for some reason, it always says that invalid cv file. I have tested all the files and my file size is well within the limits.

What might be the error ?

```
<?php
include 'classes/class.user.php';;
$userMain = new user();
$allowedExts = array("pdf", "doc", "docx");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);
var_dump($extension);
var_dump(in_array($extension, $allowedExts));
echo $_FILES["file"]["size"];



if (($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000) && in_array($extension, $allowedExts)) 
      {
        if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) 
        {
          echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
        } 
        else 
        {
          if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"])) 
          {
            echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
          } 
          else 
          {
            $rand = mt_rand(0,10000);
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
            "upload/" . $rand . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
            //echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"].$rand;
            $userMain->updateCVLink($rand.$_FILES["file"]["name"],$_SESSION['email']);
            //echo "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"].$rand;
            include 'fileuploadedsuccess.php';
          }
        }
      } 
      else 
      {
        echo "Invalid cv file";
      }
?>
```

Comment: What size are the files you're trying to upload (MB/KB)?

Comment: @I'L'I

All the files are within 500kb limit.

Comment: Are you sure you change permissions the to folder where you want to upload that file?

Comment: `if (($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000)` is a possible indicator that the maximum size is 19.5 KB.

Comment: try to check `if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)` before. Maybe there is an error. Check post_max_size value defined in php.ini

Answer (score 0, accepted):

500 kb is 512000 b, so your condition must be ;

```
if (($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 512000)
```